# how i can remove jQuery UI dialog mockup from the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

when dialog close the page have dialog mockup as hidden in page. so how i can remove them then they are removed with the mockup. means how i can remove dialog with the mockup so later their is no mockup same can found in DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you you must use `.dialog("destroy")` withe the same selector you used to create it
or if you assind the dialog to a javascript variable you call the method on the variable.

```
$('#myid').dialog("destroy")//You created it with $('#myid').dialog()
mydialog.dialog("destroy")//You created it with var mydialog = $('#myid').dialog()
```

if you want to this when you close the dialag do this when creating it:

```
$('#myid').dialog({close: $('#myid').dialog("destroy")});
```

EDIT - ok i understood you wanted to remove the dialog. To remove the html i think you can do this:

```
$('#myid').dialog({close: $('#myid').remove()});
//this removes the element with the id myid from the DOM
```

Comment: i try it but content not remove from the page. i need them with the remove of content

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var dialog = $('#my_dialog').dialog();
$('#my_dialog').dialog('destroy').remove()
```

Or put it in the close event:

```
var dialog = $('#my_dialog').dialog({
    close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
    }
});
```